# BroadcastReceiver не работает на Android 9, но работает на Android 5

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, android-broadcastreceiver, android-bluetooth

Пишу проект в Android Studio, со всеми обновлениями.
Как дебаггер использую Xperia Z на Android 5.1, который лежит дома. Недавно решил проверить на личном телефоне Pixel на Android 9, и понял, что на нём нет того же результата.
BroadcastReceiver использую для обнаружения поблизости устройств Bluetooth. Определяю и регистрирую локально, не через manifest.
Читал новые ограничения в использовании BroadcastReceiver, которые были введены в сAndroid 8, но там ничего не качается Bluetooth-устройств и, насколько я помню, касается вообще только BroadcastReceiver зарегистрированных через manifest. Мне этого не надо, слишком избыточно для ресурсов.
В чём может быть проблема? Код один и тот же. Bluetooth рабочий, ведь через встроенный интерфейс системы устройства рядом видны.

Comment: Попробуйте понизить `targetSdkVersion` проекта до, к примеру 23, и перекомпилировать. Если заработает на вашем Pixel, значит дело в версии системы, если нет, то дело в девайсе.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja попробовал, не сработало. Дело было в дополнительном разрешении на определение геопозиции, введённом в Android 6. Подробности в моём ответе ниже. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась.
Дело было в том, что начиная с Android 6 для поиска Bluetooth-устройств поблизости нужно объявить разрешение `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` в manifest.
После объявления всё в порядке.